# Add "items per page" drop down box in SHOPIFY

Tags: search, drop-down-menu, shopify, liquid

I'm building a web store on shopify. I want to add a drop down box on a page that displays my products where I can select number of items to display per page (i.e. 25, 50, 100).

Any suggestions on where to start with this and if there are any shortcodes in shopify that will help me do this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for the collection page; try the following code:

```
<div class="sort-per-page">
 <label for="sel1">Show per page:</label>
 <select id="sel1" class="num">
 <option value="/collections/{{ collection.handle }}?view=9" {% if limit == 9 %}selected="selected"{% endif %}>9</option>
 <option value="/collections/{{ collection.handle }}?view=12" {% if limit == 12 %}selected="selected"{% endif %}>12</option>
 <option value="/collections/{{ collection.handle }}?view=24" {% if limit == 24 %}selected="selected"{% endif %}>24</option>
 <option value="/collections/{{ collection.handle }}?view=36" {% if limit == 36 %}selected="selected"{% endif %}>36</option>
 </select>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.sort-per-page select.num').on('change', function(){
      window.location.replace(jQuery(this).val());
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

One thing is for sure. You will be dealing with Collections. When you render a collection, you choose the number of Products to show. Further Shopify has Pagination you setup and control.

You can thus render your selection mechanism however you choose by enacapsulating the built-in Liquid Collection rendering variables.

Alternatively, you can render ALL the products in a collection into some client-side data structure (that could take some time depending on the number of products) and then render any number of them using your own algorithms and ideas.